# I can't see change in my reputation after giving accepted answer

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, community-wiki

See my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262519/sachin-singh). I can't see any change in my reputation after receiving an accept on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263172/rails-how-to-validate-form-with-nested-attributes/27263428#27263428).

Comment: It's a community wiki. They don't generate reputation changes. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 6):

You made the post a Community Wiki post by checking a checkbox when you posted. You cannot get reputation for Community Wiki posts; the tooltip on the checkbox explains this:

<kbd>[image: community wiki checkbox and associated tooltip, with handdrawn circles and lines]</kbd>

If this was a mistake, you can flag your post for moderator attention (use the *other* option) and request that they remove the CW status. You cannot get the reputation for the votes cast so far (including the accept), but future votes will get you reputation again.