# My rating doesn't change

Tags: support, reputation

I have today answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445029/trouble-sieving-primes-from-a-large-range) which is accepted. So I should get `+15`. But my rating didn't change. Is there anything wrong with my account? What should I do now? Also in my profile page the reputation (+15) increase is not shown.

Comment: Your answer is a Community Wiki. As a result you get no rep for it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your answer is [*community wiki*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) and thus you don't get the reputation even in case it is accepted. The most probable reason for your post coming community wiki is that you checked the check box for it when composing your answer.

Comment: .: 2 questions. Can you explain it ,I mean what is whole thing? second thing..should I delete the post as it is possibly duplicate of some other question?( I have not asked this intentionally..I couldn't find it earlier)

Comment: 1. The link I provided or the link in comment starting 'possible duplicate' will explain it all. 2. No need to remove this, it will probably be marked as duplicate and that's it.

Comment: .: Is it me or the community who marked it as community wiki? Can I know it?

Comment: @coderredoc _"or the community who marked it"_ It sometimes happens if you make many edits to your post within a short time period.

Comment: @coderredoc: If you click the _edited by_ link below your original answer, you get to see the edit history of your answer. There you can see that it was you who marked it as community wiki: "Post Made Community Wiki".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ.: I think that is the case probably. Can anyone of you remove it? As the question is completely answered there?

Comment: @coderredoc you can see here about getting it reverted from a CW http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278805/1380752

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That only happened years ago, thus cannot apply to this user.

Comment: @Deduplicator Ooops. _"Time flies like a banana." G. Marx_